# Coefficients in Trigonometric Functions

Tags: trigonometry

So, previously in my math classes I have been taught that
The phase shift of $$\sin(ax+c)$$ is c.

But in my new class they say that $$ \sin(ax+c) = \sin(a(x+c))$$
which I believe to be wrong. But I have an exam tommorrow and I do not wish to be marked down for having the wrong phase shift.

Comment: The phase shift is $c$. The equation $\sin(ax+c) = \sin(a(x+c))$ is false in general (it's true if $a=1$ of course). The $a$ is the frequency parameter, and doesn't affect the phase shift. You can think of phase shift as the angle you get at time zero, or in this case when $x=0$.

Comment: So I was correct? And my professor is teaching it wrong? In the textbook it says: $$y=\csc(2x-\pi/4) = \csc 2(x-\pi/8)$$

Comment: The equation you cite from your textbook is very different from the one you display in the body of the question.

Comment: Not in theory. It is essentially the same idea. Isn't it?

Comment: No, no, no. $ax+c$ is not the same as $a(x+c)$, but $2x-(\pi/4)$ is the same as $2(x-(\pi/8))$, in theory, in practice, and in every country on this or any other planet.

Comment: Okay, Well thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be different conventions about phase shift. See this Regents [link](http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATT7/phaseshift.htm), where it says that if $$y=\sin(2x-(\pi/2))=\sin(2(x-(\pi/4)))$$ then physicists and engineers say the phase shift is $\pi/2$ but some math textbooks say it's $\pi/4$. Find out for certain which convention your class is using, and use it. If it's too late for that, then declare which convention *you* are using, and stick with it.